# Using CSS, how can I make elements move to the right letter by letter?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move letters individually from a word one-by-one to the right.
It should look like they're being pulled to that direction from the center.
Look at this pen (not mine, btw): https://codepen.io/egrucza/pen/LZdPeP .

It should be like that, except the word (in HTML) is there already and the letters should move to the right when the word is hovered on.
Now look what I've got so far in my pen: https://codepen.io/jenny0515/pen/wvpdKBz .
A piece here (but please click on my code pen link):

```
.content1 :hover {
  text-align: right;
  content: "Hair Clips";
}
.content2 :hover {
  text-align: right;
  content: "Make-up";
}
.content3 :hover {
  text-align: right;
  content: "Jewelry";
}
```

So, instead of the letters appearing from above or below, the word should be at the center of the row (as I have it in my code pen), and when at hover, the last letter of the word should move to the right, and the other letters by it should follow with a slight delay in between each first move.

How can I do that in CSS?

Comment: You'd have to break down the word to letters placed in individual spans and then use css to animate the spans

Comment: Please read [ask] and follow the guidance laid out there, especially "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also **copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the elements to animate them individually.

```
<div class="center">
 <span class="one">M</span>
 <span class="two">o</span>
 <span class="three">v</span>
 <span class="four">e</span>
```

In this CodePen I broke the letters down into spans and animate manually, there are other solutions you could use to clean up your CSS and handle the delays but this is quick and dirty.

https://codepen.io/duncanlutz/pen/XWVaBQY

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to understand the basics first. Therefore, a simple example showing the basic concepts only.

To explain:

- Use single `span` elements for the letters (most important and already mentioned by others).
- `letter:hover` should be clear.
- The `&:nth-of-type(4)` part moves the 4th letter using `translateX`.

Two more things you should know:

- The transition property in the example you have posted is a
  shorthand, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
- To my understanding, moving all letters one by one on hovering a div would require [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

**Note**: You can only move the fourth letter on hover with this example.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="letter">H</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
    <span class="letter">r</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$duration: 5s;

span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.letter:hover {
    &:nth-of-type(4) {
        transform: translateX(200px);
        transition-duration: $duration;
    }
}
```